# How to disable Resharper's overriding of Tuple names?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2017

If I create a System.ValueTuple in C# 6.0, visual studio 2017, and apply names to the variables like so:

```
(int fooA, int fooB) bar = new ValueTuple<int, int>();
```

When I go to type the following:

```
bar.fooA = ....
```

Resharper always autocorrects it to this

```
bar.Item1 = ....
```

Even though Intellisense shows me the named values and I can select them, and if I manually rewrite it back to bar.FooA it still works fine. So resharper just has no idea how to handle this.

Resharper also really struggles with these Tuples and suggests a lot of formatting that breaks itself, and are just plain wrong. For example:

[image: foobar]

Suggestion #1: 'int' makes my code become this:

```
var bar = new ValueTuple<int, int>();
bar.fooA = 1;
```

Which of course means the second line is now very broken.

Suggestion #2: 'new' does this:

```
(int fooA, int fooB) bar = new ValueTuple<int, int> {Item1 = 1};
```

Which completely defeats the purpose of naming my tuple values.

Anyone know what part of Resharper's C# options will stop this? Mostly the first one is the big annoyance for me.

Comment: Which R# version you have?

Comment: Haha I just needed an update it seems, I guess one of the latest patches fixed this! Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Looks like this was fixed in R# 2017 or later.